Does rolling larger numbers first provide an edge in a game where players remove cups based on die rolls?
For New Year’s Eve, we played a game with the following rules:

Each of two players starts with 9 cups and a die.
On each turn, a player rolls the die and removes the number of cups corresponding to the die roll.
If the number rolled exceeds the number of cups available, that turn is skipped (no cups are removed).
The game ends when the total number of cups removed by a player equals exactly 9.

The question I have is:
Is there any hypothetical edge or advantage in rolling larger numbers first, or is there a specific strategy involving combinations of die rolls that could increase the chance of winning?

As I see it, here there is only one strategy for each player: at each turn, roll the die and then follow the instructions.

Is the goal to have cups left over or to remove cups? Also I agree with Iosif, I see no strategy.
